# How do I create a credit message for an image as a hyperlink in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am inserting an image in rmarkdown with a message below it that says "Image by John Doe". I want to make that credit message a hyperlink to a website (say [www.johndoe.com](http://www.johndoe.com)). The code below adds the image and the credit message as text (not a hyperlink)

```
![Image by John Doe](Image.jpg){width="70%"}
```

How do I convert the message into a hyperlink. I tried the following which did NOT work

```
![Image by John Doe)(https://www.johndoe.com)(Image.jpg){width="70%}
```

Comment: I recognize you are trying things and *that* did not work ... but *that* attempt has unbalanced brackets, parens, and quotes. Untested, but have you tried something like `![Image by [John Doe](https://www.johndoe.com)](Image.jpg){width="70%"}`?

Comment: @r2evans Your code worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
![Image by [John Doe](https://www.johndoe.com)](Image.jpg){width="70%"}
```

Be careful (in markdown) to always properly balance brackets, parentheses, and quotes; in your example:

```
![Image by John Doe)(https://www.johndoe.com)(Image.jpg){width="70%}
 ^                 ^                                           ^
 |                 |                           no matching " --'
 |                 `-- no matching ")"
 `-- no matching "]"
```

Comment: TheRookie, did this answer your question?